# Autocomplete not working for test files

Tags: xcode

Code completion has been a continuing issue for me and lately there's been a new wrinkle.  Normally I can just delete the derived data folder and rebuild, sometimes having to exit Xcode, but now I've hit an issue I can't solve.

Auto complete is working in my base project, by that I mean if I'm in a file that is building with the program, code completion works.  But if I start writing a test case in a code module that builds with the test target) completion will not work with any of the main target classes or variables.

I have @testable import [target] and it's been working in the past.

The only thing I've done recently is move my repo off my iCloud drive because it was causing Xcode to crash whenever a did a pull onto a local hard drive location.

Is there some location in the project settings that determine where Xcode looks? Is there some hidden cache I need to delete?  programming without code completion is a nightmare.

Using the latest 8.2.1 Xcode with all my code in Swift 3.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 29):

I have encountered the same problem under Xcode 10.1. The issue seemed to be related to the Build configuration settings of the currently used scheme.  Namely, mine were different for the different actions, e.g. Release for the Run action and Debug for the Test action. Changing the build configuration of the Run action to Debug (thus matching the test action one) fixed the issue for me.

Steps I used:

1. Select your scheme (top left)
2. Select "Edit scheme"
3. Make sure the Test and Run actions are using the same build configuration

   3.1 If not, select the corresponding action (Test or Run), choose the "Info" tab and change the Configuration from the corresponding picker

Comment: Thank you! :) After doing this I did the steps suggested by [@sja26 in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43273627/4666760) then it was solved for me.

Comment: @KnutValen, happy to hear it has helped

Comment: Is it possible to fix this whilst keeping a dedicated testing build configuration?

Comment: Hi @DeclanMcKenna, I tried and had no luck so far getting it to work with a dedicated build config.

Comment: Issue persists with XCode 12.1. Changing targets fixes the issue and after changing back to a dedicated test target seems to work as expected :| Any news?

Answer (score 27):

I encountered the same problem recently, what I had been trying was:

1. Cleaning my build folder <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
2. Building my test target <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

I mistakenly believed Xcode 8.2.1 would build my main target, given that it's a `@testable import` in my unit test classes.

So the steps that worked in the end were:

1. Cleaning my build folder <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
2. **Building my main target <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>**
3. Building my test target <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

After which both the code completion and syntax highlighting return as expected.

Comment: just when i think xcode can't get any worse it continues to surprise me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ivan-s-ivanov [you were spot on regarding build config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53590724/1311272), to expand a little bit more on your answer - **it also applies to projects using `.xcconfig` files**.

[Fix in this commit in our open source app](https://github.com/radixdlt/babylon-wallet-ios/pull/860/commits/6da84c7c97d36b24cbc5de425b8ef37df7e528b3), there seems to be a subtle detail regarding projects with `.xcconfig`, and it is you have to set the `xcconfig` for Unit test target to the same as the app target.

See screenshot below, what I did is I changed from `None` to the same `.xcconfig` as the app target:

**BEFORE (no autocomplete)**
[image: Before]

**AFTER (autocomplete works)**
[image: After]

Hope this helps someone!